Properties file locations for ProducerConfig and ConsumerConfig when running connect-distributed.sh
I am new to kafka and kafka-connect.
I want to do a data migration from MongoDB to Atlas MongoDB via MongoDB Kafka Connect.
I am using kafka 2.12-2.3.0 version and uses mongo-kafka-connect-1.13.0-all.jar for kafka-connect.
After starting zookeeper and kafka, I am running connect-distributed like:
cd /opt/kafka_2.12-2.3.0
sudo bash bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties &disown

After starting or running connect-distributed I get the log showing both ProducerConfig and ConsumerConfig
ProducerConfig
[2024-09-25 07:13:37,742] INFO ProducerConfig values: 
  acks = all
  batch.size = 16384
  bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
  buffer.memory = 33554432
  client.dns.lookup = default
  client.id = 
  compression.type = none
  connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
  delivery.timeout.ms = 2147483647
  enable.idempotence = false
  interceptor.classes = []
  key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
  linger.ms = 0
  max.block.ms = 60000
  max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
  max.request.size = 1048576
  metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
  metric.reporters = []
  metrics.num.samples = 2
  metrics.recording.level = INFO
  metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
  partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
  receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
  reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
  reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
  request.timeout.ms = 30000
  retries = 2147483647
  retry.backoff.ms = 100
  sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
  sasl.jaas.config = null
  sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
  sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
  sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
  sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
  sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
  sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
  sasl.login.class = null
  sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
  sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
  sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
  sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
  sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
  security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
  send.buffer.bytes = 131072
  ssl.cipher.suites = null
  ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
  ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
  ssl.key.password = null
  ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
  ssl.keystore.location = null
  ssl.keystore.password = null
  ssl.keystore.type = JKS
  ssl.protocol = TLS
  ssl.provider = null
  ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
  ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
  ssl.truststore.location = null
  ssl.truststore.password = null
  ssl.truststore.type = JKS
  transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
  transactional.id = null
  value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig:347)

ConsumerConfig
[2024-09-25 07:13:37,750] INFO ConsumerConfig values: 
  allow.auto.create.topics = true
  auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
  auto.offset.reset = earliest
  bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
  check.crcs = true
  client.dns.lookup = default
  client.id = 
  client.rack = 
  connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
  default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
  enable.auto.commit = false
  exclude.internal.topics = true
  fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
  fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
  fetch.min.bytes = 1
  group.id = connect-cluster
  group.instance.id = null
  heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
  interceptor.classes = []
  internal.leave.group.on.close = true
  isolation.level = read_uncommitted
  key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
  max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
  max.poll.records = 500
  metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
  metric.reporters = []
  metrics.num.samples = 2
  metrics.recording.level = INFO
  metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
  partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
  receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
  reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
  reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
  request.timeout.ms = 30000
  retry.backoff.ms = 100
  sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
  sasl.jaas.config = null
  sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
  sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
  sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
  sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
  sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
  sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
  sasl.login.class = null
  sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
  sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
  sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
  sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
  sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
  security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
  send.buffer.bytes = 131072
  session.timeout.ms = 10000
  ssl.cipher.suites = null
  ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
  ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
  ssl.key.password = null
  ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
  ssl.keystore.location = null
  ssl.keystore.password = null
  ssl.keystore.type = JKS
  ssl.protocol = TLS
  ssl.provider = null
  ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
  ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
  ssl.truststore.location = null
  ssl.truststore.password = null
  ssl.truststore.type = JKS
  value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:347)

What I want to achieve is to update the defaults in ProducerConfig's max.request.size = 1048576 and increase it to something like max.request.size =10485760.
Same with ConsumerConfig's max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576 and increase it like max.partition.fetch.bytes = 10485760.
My problem now is where can I find these properties files.
Below are the list of configurations in /opt/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/config:
butitoy@my-server:/opt/kafka_2.12-2.3.0$ ls -l config/
total 68
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  906 Jun 19  2019 connect-console-sink.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  909 Jun 19  2019 connect-console-source.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5482 Sep 25 02:36 connect-distributed.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  883 Jun 19  2019 connect-file-sink.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  881 Jun 19  2019 connect-file-source.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1552 Jun 19  2019 connect-log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2290 Sep 24 04:03 connect-standalone.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1344 Sep 25 05:33 consumer.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4727 Jun 19  2019 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1933 Sep 25 05:33 producer.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6925 Sep 24 15:24 server.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1032 Jun 19  2019 tools-log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1169 Jun 19  2019 trogdor.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1023 Jun 19  2019 zookeeper.properties
butitoy@my-server:/opt/kafka_2.12-2.3.0$ 

I tried adding max.request.size in server.properties and producer.properties, and max.partition.fetch.bytes in consumer.properties. Even in connect-distributed.properties, the changes were not reflected in ProducerConfig and ConsumerConfig.
How do I change the default values and what config/properties files do I need to change?

Kafka Connect does not read the server, consumer, or producer properties files
If you must set client configs, you'd do it in the connect-distributed.properties file,
as written in the docs.

For configuration of the producers used by Kafka source tasks and the consumers used by Kafka sink tasks, the same parameters can be used but need to be prefixed with producer. and consumer. respectively

Or at the individual connector level

Starting with 2.3.0, client configuration overrides can be configured individually per connector by using the prefixes producer.override. and consumer.override.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_running
You shouldn't need sudo to run Kafka Connect, and if possible, I'd recommend upgrading to latest Kafka, as there have been improvements in both client rebalancing protocols, transactions, as well as Connect features.
